# In C++ OOP, who is responsible to delete object passed to constructor

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, garbage

For example,

> I have an account generator class need a random method to decide
>   username and password. Random has many ways to implement, so it is an
>   interface with many subclass. Account generator class accept Random
>   object in constructor.

In Java we don't care the deletion of object. But I'm now doing it in C++.
My question is, if I did the following in main()

```
Random random=new StdRandom();
AccGen accGen=new AccGen(random);
```

should I delete "random" in main(), or I should put it in the destructor of AccGen?

> Edit:
>
> Even after the question is being answered very well, I think I may
>   still state the reason that why do I use pointer, in order to help
>   somebody facing the same problem.
>
> The reason I use pointer, is to apply many patterns like Factory and
>   Behavior. Non-pointer variable seems not able to be an Interface with
>   pure virtual method, which cannot present overrides.
>
> In a design view, I think the creator of an object is always
>   responsible for its deletion. That is why it makes me confused. All
>   the caller wants, it an AccGen object. I passed a random object is to
>   decide the implementation of Random, inside AccGen. Then Random object
>   is not a participant in caller's level, then why should the caller be
>   responsible for its deletion. But the fact is, in some case, the
>   random is useful in the following actions in caller's level. The given
>   example is really just an example.
>
> After a study of smart pointer, Unique pointer really is the solution
>   of my problem. It makes **pointer become more specific**, in terms of to state 
>   the purpose of creating such pointer.
>
> **To summarize, if an object is useful after passed to constructor, then
>   the type would be pure pointer and with no deletion in destructor. If
>   the object is useless in caller's level, then the type should be
>   unique pointer.**

Comment: In Java, who is responsible for potential non-memory resources?

Comment: It depends entirely on you. The concept is called *ownership* - the owner of the resource is responsible for cleaning up, but it's up to you to decide who is the owner. However, in modern C++ you shouldn't use `new` - use smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. This way you have clear ownership and you *never* have to worry about deleting objects.

Comment: How does `AccGen` know that pointer was created with a call to `new`?  You could have given it the address of a non-allocated object, i.e. `Random random; AccGen accGen(&random);` -- So you can't simply equate C++ to Java or try to figure out what to do with C++ given how Java operates.

Comment: This is the curse of manual memory management. The responsible party is whoever's been specified by the design to be the responsible party. The general rule of thumb is to [not design your way into problems like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new).

Comment: Do you have `using Random = StdRandom*;` somewhere or what is `Random random=new StdRandom();` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Actually the code I posted was in Java. But I think my question is answered, the smart pointer. Thx everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, if I did the following in main()
>
> ```
> Random random=new StdRandom();
> AccGen accGen=new AccGen(random);
> ```

The thing is: You dont. `Random` is a not a pointer type (unless it is a misleading alias for `SomeOtherType*`) but `new` returns you a pointer to the object it creates.

If you need dynamic allocations you can do it manually with raw pointers and take the full responsibility of `delete`ing things you created via `new`:

```
Random* random = new StdRandom();
AccGen* accGen = new AccGen(random);
// ... do something ...
delete accGen;
delete random;
```

It helps to get acustomed to the concept of ownership. If one object is responsible to manage the lifetime of a second instance, it is said to "own" that instance.

Further, resources are acquired in the constructor and released in the destructor (read about [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) if you want to know more). Hence, you could consider to let `accGen` take responsibility for deleting `random` in its destructor (*).

Doing this manually is neither recommended nor necessary. Use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers). You can forget about `new` and `delete` if you just let smart pointers do the dirty work. There is no garbage in C++, though consistently using `std::shared_ptr`  is probably what is closest to using a garbage collector.

Anyhow, if you do not need to allocate memory dynamically, then do not. C++ has value semantics. In C++ you get more than just references to objects, you get the objects.

```
int main {
    StdRandom random;
    AccGen accGen{random};
    // ... use accGen ...
}   // <- end of scope
```

No need to delete anything. Objects on the stack get their destructor called when going out of scope.

(*) = If a function gets passed a raw pointer, it is not expected to take ownership of the pointed to object. The function cannot know if it is allocated on the stack or dynamically.

Comment: Probable typo: To keep the same (assumed) pointer syntax, `AccGen accGen{random};` should be `AccGen accGen{&random};`

Comment: @user4581301 actually it was on purpose to have the last example without any pointers. Very likely a `StdRandom` is not copyable, but i didnt want to bloat the answer with more discussion

Comment: @LeePaiChan Smart pointer *could* be the answer. Unfortunately there is no way to be sure from the example given in the question. Nothing in the example suggests you need more than an [Automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable). Remember that unlike in Java [you do not have to `new` objects](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/value-vs-ref-semantics). Where possible let the runtime take care of the management for you.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ we use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) so then we don't care about delete.